# Can not concactenate str ("not list")?

Tags: python

> I get an error which is TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str. How do I join all addresses together with a separator using "|" ?

```
def make_api_url(**kwargs):
        data = pd.read_csv('bitcoinaddr.csv')
        Wallet_Address = (data.loc[:, "Address"])
        BASE_URL = "https://blockchain.info/balance"
        print (Wallet_Address)
        for address in Wallet_Address:
            print (address)
            url = BASE_URL + [f"?active={address}"] #error
            print(url)
        
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
             url += f"&{key}={value}"
             return url
    
    get_balance_url = make_api_url()
```

Comment: The error says that in python you cannot join string with python.
remove [ ]  from this line : url = BASE_URL + [f"?active={address}"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```py
address = '|'.join(Wallet_Address)
url = BASE_URL + f"?active={addresses}"
```

That is, build the pipe separated string of addresses first, then append it one time to the URL as a query parameter.